# .noSuchElementException when asking the user for input

Tags: java

I can't run the following piece of code. I would like to know why I keep getting the .noSuchElementException error. I've seen in another post is due to the fact I'm using the same Input stream for both inputs, but creating a new Scanner or using the .close method doesn't seem to fix my problem.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int tooBig = 0; // parts too big
        int tooSmall = 0; // parts too small
        int perfectParts= 0; // perfect parts

        int a = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();
        for (int i = 0; i <= a ; i++) {
            int j = scanner.nextInt();

            if(j == 1) {
                tooBig++;
            } else if (j == -1) {
                tooSmall++;
            } else if (j == 0) {
                perfectParts++;
            }
            scanner.close();
        }

        System.out.println(perfectParts + " " + tooBig
                + " " + tooSmall);



    }
}
```

Edit after having removed the scanner.close() method. I still get the same error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        int tooBig = 0; // parts too big
        int tooSmall = 0; // parts too small
        int perfectParts= 0; // perfect parts

        int a = scanner.nextInt();


        for (int i = 0; i <= a ; i++) {
            int j = scanner.nextInt();

            if(j == 1) {
                tooBig++;
            } else if (j == -1) {
                tooSmall++;
            } else if (j == 0) {
                perfectParts++;
            }

        }


        System.out.println(perfectParts + " " + tooBig
                + " " + tooSmall);



    }
}
```

Comment: you are closing the scanner in the for loop. that means you are closing it multiple times, and then while it is closed you are asking for another input

Comment: try putting `scanner.close();` after the for loop instead of inside

Comment: ...and you're closing it once even before you enter the loop.  Take out all of the `scanner.close()` calls and see what you get.

Comment: `scanner`can't do `nextInt()` if you invoke `close()` first.

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions and none seem to have worked. I keep getting the error.

Comment: I am not getting any error with your edited version

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's a problem from JetBrains so I guess it's gotta be their mistake.

Comment: This is a pretty basic piece of code. I highly doubt it's a problem with the IDE. Never close Scanner when streaming **System.in**. Once closed it can not be used again until you restart your application. Only close it when you know you will never need it again for the remaining duration of your Application.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int tooBig = 0; // parts too big
    int tooSmall = 0; // parts too small
    int perfectParts= 0; // perfect parts

    int a = scanner.nextInt();

    
    for (int i = 0; i <= a ; i++) {
        int j = scanner.nextInt();

        if(j == 1) {
            tooBig++;
        } else if (j == -1) {
            tooSmall++;
        } else if (j == 0) {
            perfectParts++;
        }
        
    }

    System.out.println(perfectParts + " " + tooBig
            + " " + tooSmall);

    scanner.close();

}
}
```

Comment: the scanner has to be open before you call one of its methods so if you just close it at the end of your code it should stop throwing errors

Comment: Hello! I still get the eror.

Comment: Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at Main.main(Main.java:16)

Comment: did you remove all other `scanner.close();` calls? there should only be one at the very end

Comment: Yes. I've tried both not using scanner.close(); or only using one. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`scanner.close();` Should only be called at the very end. It's also not even necessary in your specific case and likely the reason why you're getting that exception.